# How to reload/reopen the same form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to reload the current form (not the main form) whenever both of the radio buttons are unchecked. I did this but it won't work.

```
StreamWriter sw;
using (sw = File.CreateText(path))
{
    if (OnewayRadio.Checked == true)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("One Way Ticket");
    }
    else if (RoundRadio.Checked == true)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Round Trip");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have not selected your type of trip!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        sw.Close();
        File.Delete(path);
        sw = File.CreateText(path);
    }
    sw.WriteLine("Name: " + name.Text);
    sw.WriteLine("Number: " + number.Text);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by current form? Is it the main form in your application or are you opening it from another form?

Comment: Whatever else you are doing, don't close the StreamWriter, delete the file, then try to write to it.  That's going to be a problem.

Comment: Also, there's nothing in the snippet you posted that has anything to do with closing or opening a form.

Comment: If you'd use a [Radio Button Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx), you wouldn't need that check at all because there would always be one checked.

Comment: If i forgot to check any of the radio button, in that case i want to reload the form.

Comment: Chris berger, sir if I donot close the file it gives a runtime error which says: "The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: I didn't say that you shouldn't close the file - the end of your `using` block will do that automatically.  I said, don't close the file and delete it and THEN try to write to it.  Maybe don't create the file until after you've validated your inputs.

Comment: I did just notice that you've re-initialized sw after you deleted the file.  But it seems like a very bad idea to reinitialize the variable that you have placed a `using` block around.  I don't know what the behavior will be.

Comment: When i am not closing, it is throwing exception that it is used by another process.

Comment: What do you mean by "Reload"? Close and Re-open, or just call Form_Load()?

Comment: That's because you're trying to delete the file while it's open.  Don't do that.  Ask yourself WHY you are creating a file, then validating inputs, and then deleting the file if the inputs don't validate.  And also, why you are doing this inside of a using block.

Comment: @RufusL sir either of the two will do that for me.

Comment: @ChrisBerger so I should clear all of the text, coming from inputs, written on that file and then rewrite all of the text from inputs.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to open a form using `ShowDialog`

When your code in the form completes executing it will set a public  `DialogResult`

The caller can then read the `DialogResult` and take any necessary action.

In your case, you can set the `DialogResult` to `Retry` for this specific instance. The opener can then run a loop and continue to show the form again while `ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Retry`

```
Form2 testDialog = new Form2();

// Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
while (testDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult. Retry)
{
    testDialog.Dispose();
    testDialog = null;
    testDialog = new Form2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer here assumes that the form to reopen is allowed to be modal. That is not always the case. I ran into the issue when making a form non-modal instead of modal.

Use .Hide() instead of .Close().

Place the Hide in the FormClosing() event like so,

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
      Hide();
      e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

After the form is "closed" in this way, a next call to Show() will have no  issue.

In my case, some actions after closing the form had to be executed. If you normally open in Modal state, the ShowDialog() will return when the form is closed, like so

```
    {
      // ..

      form1.ShowDialog();
      OperationsAfterClose(form1);

      // .. 
   }
```

A non-modal call form.Show() will return immediately. So any epilogue like my OperationsAfterClose() would be called immediately.

I used a delegate to move the action, as follows,

```
   public delegate void OnFormHide(FrmMapFerryAnalysisSpec2 f);

   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public OnFormHide OnForm1Hide = null;
      // ..
   

      private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
      {
        if (OnForm1Hide!=null) OnForm1Hide (this);   // call the delegate
        Hide();
        e.Cancel = true;
      }

      // ..
  }
```

In the calling form I can now pass OperationsAfterClose() as a delegate,

```
{
    // ..
    form1.Show();
    form1.OnForm1Hide = OperationsAfterClose;     // set the delegate

    // .. 
}
```

*NOTES:*

- in order to use this safely, the form1 handle should exist and must not be created multiple times !
- Also in most applications, the form may only open once. To do that, easiest is to introduce a IsOpenForm1 boolean in the calling form.